# Calendar functionality

Tags: java

Input date is `2016-01-01`, but why output shows `2016/02/01`?

```
String df = "2016-01-01";
String enddate="";
SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT_QUERY = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'");

Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
String[] dateStr=df.split("-"); 
int year=Integer.parseInt(dateStr[0]);
int month=Integer.parseInt(dateStr[1]);
int day=Integer.parseInt(dateStr[2]);
cal.set(year,month,day,23, 59,59);
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
enddate=DATE_FORMAT_QUERY.format(cal.getTime());
System.out.println(enddate);
```

Output:

```
Mon Feb 01 23:59:59 EST 2016 20160201T235959Z
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the input date as well instead of doing that yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION**

> Input date is 2016-01-01, but why output shows 2016/02/01?

**Because [Calendar::month](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) is 0-based.**

> `month` - the value used to set the `MONTH` calendar field. **Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January.**

You should use

```
int month=Integer.parseInt(dateStr[1] - 1);
```

---

**CORRECT SOLUTION**

**NEVER** parse manually a `String` containing a `Date`, better get date with `SimpleDateFormat` and use it to set `Calendar` time:

```
SimpleDateFormat dfo = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(dfo.parse("2016-01-01"));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 2016
20160101T000000Z
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: glad to help `;)`

Comment: @PanayappanSwaminathan as long as [you never accept any answer in your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5168236/panayappan-swaminathan?tab=questions) you must know if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Of course there is no obligation to do this.